# ld.exe has stopped working

Tags: c, ld

I am using Dev-C++ V(4.9.9.2) and trying to build a solution that performs some system based programming specifically that calls the **Windows Service Manager**. Now whenever I try to build my application, it halts with a message 
**ld.exe has stopped working** and the application stops. I don't understand why this is happening when everything else falls right in place.

Comment: What is the version of gcc and ld used? Have you tried updating them? What happens if you try to build your project (compile and link) from the command line?

Comment: Check the compatibility of your libraries with 64 versus 32 bit. I got this issue a lot when I was transitioning from 32 to 64 bit MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Dev-C++. It is ancient and so is its compiler.

Use a modern compiler environment like those available at http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/, or get an IDE with a newer MinGW(-w64) compiler, like Qt Creator, CodeBlocks, or even http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/, etc...